# VBA: evaluation order

Tags: vba, operator-precedence

when VBA executes this line:

```
GetClass1().Test(GetParam())
```

the `GetParam` function is evaluated before the `GetClass1()` call.

What is a good way to change this behaviour?

the only thing I came up with is this workaround:

```
With GetClass1
    .Test(GetParam())
End With
```

---

here's the full example code, so that you can easily test it:

**Class1**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Test(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Debug.Print "Class1.Text: " & sText
    Test = "Class1.Text: " & sText
End Function
```

**Module1**
    Option Explicit

```
Private Function GetClass1() As Class1
    Set GetClass1 = New Class1
    Debug.Print "GetClass1()"
End Function

Private Function GetParam() As String
    GetParam = "Param"
    Debug.Print "GetParam()"
End Function


Private Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "Test=" + GetClass1().Test(GetParam())

    With GetClass1
        Debug.Print "TestWith=" + .Test(GetParam())
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output** when you run `Test()`

```
GetParam()
GetClass1()
Class1.Text: Param
Test=Class1.Text: Param

GetClass1()
GetParam()
Class1.Text: Param
TestWith=Class1.Text: Param
```

Comment: ...and this is a problem because....? Since you get the same result, does it really matter?

Comment: most of the time it does not matter - but in advanced use-cases it can be a problem: e.g. when used in an Error-handler and `GetClass1()` wants to read the Err object info (Number, etc.). with the "default" evaluation order this is not possible, because `GetParam()` will reset the `Err` object.

Comment: The Err object is a special case. Is there another case where it's a problem. If I change the line in GetParam to `GetParam = Err.Description` that description gets passed to Class1 and printed out as expected. I'm not sure what you're seeing that's resetting it.

Comment: IMHO the `Err` object is not a special case - you have the same behaviour if any other global variable or object is used/altered in 2 palces. From my point of view this is a surprise since it's not like that in other languages I've worked before and after all the `GetClass1()` call may raise an exception or return `Nothing` - so calling `GetParam()` seems wrong (to me at least).
but anyway - it is the way it is in VBA - so let's please get back to my original question: "What is a good way to change this behaviour?"

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation order here is ok i think. The calling order of nested functions is from the inner most one to the outer most one which can't be done differently because outer most function needs to know its arguments and this arguments are evalueted only after the inner function was executed.

In your code (the first way) the object of type Class1 is created after the function GetParam() was called and this is because the object is created at the moment when function GetClass1() is called. In the second way with `With GetClass1` the object is created immedialtelly after With and the call stack looks differently indeed.

What you can do is to create another class say 'Wrap' and this class will be responsible for creation of instance of type Class1.

E.g. like this:

```
' Class module Wrap
Private m_class1 As Class1

Public Function GetClass1() As Class1
    Set GetClass1 = m_class1
    Debug.Print "GetClass1()"
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_class1 = New Class1
End Sub  

' Module code
Private Function GetParam() As String
    GetParam = "Param"
    Debug.Print "GetParam()"
End Function

Private Sub Test()
    Dim wp As Wrap
    Set wp = New Wrap

    Debug.Print "Test=" + wp.GetClass1().Test(GetParam())

    Debug.Print "---------------------------------------"

    With New Wrap
        Debug.Print "TestWith=" + .GetClass1.Test(GetParam())
    End With
End Sub
```

Here the instance of class Class1 is created exactly at the moment you call New for class Wrap. So `Set wp = New Wrap` executes and creates the instance and the same way works `With New Wrap`, it executes and creates the instance as well.

But do not do it like this:

```
Dim wp As New Wrap
```

... then you will have the same behaviour like you had when the function GetClass1() was part of the Module1, which is: **'the instance is not created until it is needed'** so you do not have the control of the moment of creation. HTH

Comment: As I see it, your approach works because of the new variable, that is explicitly defined in it's own line of code (which has basically the same effect as the `with` line in the original example). I don't see any benefit in this wrapper class. Introducing a new temporary variable of type `Class1` would have the same effect (with less code):
<br />
   `Dim tmp As Class1`<br />
   `Set tmp = GetClass1`<br />
   `Debug.Print "Test=" + tmp.Test(GetParam())`<br />
<br />
so what is the benefit of this new wrapper class?

Comment: Yes this would have the same effect. Benefit? That the function GetClass1 still exists in the same structure, but it does not create the instance directly any more. Well I not know exactly what are you trying to achieve so maybe my answer is totally useless :-).